# Where is the Volume Control in an iPod Touch?

Tags: ipod-touch

I have an iPod touch for my teen who continues to put the volume on high. My son has ASD and always wants everything set to high.

There is no volume control password option, how do I get this?

Comment: Which iOS version is installed on [which version of iPod touch](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1353)?

Answer (score 1):

You first have to turn on Parental Control and then you can enforce a maximum volume limit.

Apple's article on parental controls and guided tutorial should let you configure your son's device.

- http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4213
- http://www.apple.com/support/ipod/